# Second job in chained ampersand crontab still running even if previous one failed. Why?

Tags: bash, shell, cron

I have a cron job in my crontab as follows:

```
0 08 * * 6 /usr/bin/sh path_to_first_bash_file.sh >> job_result-`/bin/date +\%F`.log 2>&1 && /usr/bin/sh path_to_second_bash_file.sh >> job_result-`/bin/date +\%F`.log 2>&1
```

On checking the log in my `job_result-<YYYY-MM-DD>.log`, I find that `path_to_first_bash_file.sh` has failed with exit status code 1 and `path_to_second_bash_file.sh` proceeds to run.

As per *&&* idea, the second job should not proceed if the first one generates non zero exit status.

What could be the issue with my cron command?

Comment: Put your line in a thrird script and execute it by the cron.
It's better to understand it, modify it and fix problems

Comment: Are you sure the first script actually *exits* with status code 1, as opposed to just reporting an error code 1 in the log?

Comment: Following the above comments I suggest you examine the exit codes using `$?` to make sure.